# What is this metal piece on top of my threshold called?

Tags: doors, threshold

What is this metal piece on top of my threshold called? I'm asking because I am looking to purchase the same one for another exterior door in my house.

[image]

Comment: It's a proprietary component that doesn't really have a name and that you won't find in stores and likely can't even get from the manufacturer. You might make do with a carpet transition strip.

Comment: I've edited your photo - please confirm whether you mean the outer/left strip A or the inner/right strip B, as there are two types in the picture.

Comment: @isherwood - I've asked the OP for clarification, but you could get either of those in any big box store. The left is pretty standard 'no-match' flat trim, the right will probably be a **⊂**-shape & be fixed *under* the last board, meaning you'd have to lift boards to get to it. It might even be a single sided carpet edge re-purposed as a board edge.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but... links or it didn't happen. :D The one you provided below isn't to a particular product. I don't see one that matches. Also, they're for flooring transitions, not door thresholds.

Comment: @isherwood - i can't find an example of the flat bar exactly like that - but I had a houseful of it until I changed all the carpets about 5 years ago. The carpet strip - https://www.remlandcarpets.co.uk/accessories/aluminium-door-bars/single-silver

Comment: I'm not sure how that would fit on a threshold. I was thinking of things like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/TrafficMaster-Satin-Nickel-2-in-x-144-in-Aluminum-Carpet-Trim-Transition-Strip-H6034SN12/308371103), but even that's not an exact match.

Comment: @isherwood - can't view homedepot links from here, they just come up access denied. This is the simplest ceapest modern 'flat' bar I can find - https://www.screwfix.com/p/carpet-cover-door-strip-aluminium-0-9m-x-36mm/71602 - the other one, btw, was what I think 'B' is, even though it should be right-angle.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 'threshold bar' or strip, 'threshold transition bar/strip', 'joint strip' or 'joint trim'.

Any big box DIY store will stock many types, in many finishes.

If you're not sure which type you need - they depend on what material is on each side & the relative heights - then take that picture & one of your proposed new site to the store with you, & ask.

What you appear to have in your photo are two of different types, rather than a single transition strip.

Some examples - https://www.wickes.co.uk/Products/Flooring/Flooring-Tools+Accessories/Flooring-Threshold-Bars/c/1000907

Comment: thanks for your answer. I’m thinking about taking this approach and adding a door sweep with a seal to my door. Although I’m wondering if I’d be better off getting a more modern aluminum sill and threshold for a better seal.

Comment: idk just from looking at the picture, but if you want s sealing strip, then you're looking for a 'threshold sealing strip', also in a myriad styles - see https://www.ironmongerydirect.co.uk/browse/hinges-seals-and-intumescent/seals/threshold-seals

Comment: That threshold strip that is  marked with the letter  "A" may be adjustable up and down. Try turning the screws heads and see if that piece will move up and down. I have a similar one and mine adjusts.

Answer (score 0):

They are transition strips and, as Tetsujin mentioned, there are a number of different types.  Most of the wood ones we looked at when doing some flooring did end up combining one or more pieces with a base and the number and selection depends on the height differential, profile, and surfaces on either side of the transition.

Since that one appears to have some insulation, it may be filed near the doorway/threshold sections of your local home improvement store instead of the flooring section.